# How to use a variable that I defined in the html of component 1 , in the ts of component 2?

Tags: angular

I have two components, `slideshow` and `center`.

In the `center.html` I declared a specific id inside the div:

```
<app-slideshow id="/pictures/center1"> </app-slideshow>
```

and I'd like to keep the variable "id"  that I set in the app-slideshow div, so I can use it in later function in `slideshow.ts`.

(I want the function to execute according to the id it receives).

What should be written instead: ??? for the variable "path" to save what we passed in "id" in `center.html`?

slideshow.ts:

```
private path= ???
```

It can help me a lot, thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you've done is set the `id` property of `<app-slideshow>` to the string `/pictures/center1`.

If you want to `input` a variable to `<app-slideshow>`, you should be using Angulars [Input Decorator](https://angular.io/api/core/Input).

```
<app-slideshow [inputVar]="'/pictures/center1'"> </app-slideshow>
```

Inside of `<app-slideshow>`:

```
import { Input } from '@angular/core';
```

[...]

```
@Input()
  public inputVar: string;
```